# edsdk capture high frame rate

Tags: c++, camera, edsdk

We have to make **3d** scan system using `Canon eos 600 d`. So we want to capture a photo at `30~60 fps`. Normally capture can't be more `3.7 fps`. So using live view in EDSDK, can I capture a photo by `30~60 fps`?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 0):

A Canon cameras live view has 30fps and a substantially smaller resolution than the photo resolution (actual resolution depends on camera model).
If the live view resolution is enough for you, there is still a problem with the transfer rate of USB 2. In my experience you won't get more than 20-25 fps at best. If your camera supports USB 3 you might be able to get better results.

I think you will be better off using something that is more specialized for this kind of thing.

Comment: eos 600d use usb 2.0, we are satisfied with 20-25 fps. can i receive your code?? I need more help about making code but i have no senior in this company..

Comment: @LetUsLoveJust I have written a tutorial in C# but it should be relatively easy to apply things to other C-based languages: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp